# In a data frame I want to duplicate rows with a certain condition in another column

Tags: r

I want to duplicate all rows with treatment C 3 times. How do I do that?

```
A <- sample(1:100,9)
B <- sample(1:100,9)
trt <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3) 

df <- data.frame(trt, A, B)
> df
  trt  A  B
1   A 82 57
2   B 76  2
3   C 12 82
4   A 87 25
5   B 64 86
6   C 74 89
7   A  4 80
8   B 31 13
9   C 39 88
```

I have tried this but it doesn't get right!

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, 2))

if (df[df$trt=="C",]){
  data.frame(rep(df,3))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rustic but effective, simply subset and `rbind`

```
rbind(df, df[trt =="C",], df[trt =="C",])
```

Here it's just joining together the original data.frame and two subsets that only contain rows where trt is C.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the row numbers when `trt == C` and then use `rep` to repeat them

```
inds <- which(df$trt == "C")
df[sort(c(1:nrow(df), rep(inds, 2))), ]

#    trt  A  B
#1     A 34 58
#2     B  2 11
#3     C 57 67
#3.1   C 57 67
#3.2   C 57 67
#4     A 77 99
#5     B 37 70
#6     C 93 46
#6.1   C 93 46
#6.2   C 93 46
#7     A 61 17
#8     B 24  1
#9     C 16 54
#9.1   C 16 54
#9.2   C 16 54
```

---

Another concept can be to `filter` rows where  `trt == "C"`, repeat them and bind to rows where `trt != "C"`. Using `dplyr`, we can implement it as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(trt == "C") %>%
  slice(rep(row_number(), 3)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(trt != "C"))
```